How to Remove Caps for HMI Door Pins
looking for any advice on removing these pins to avoid unscrewing the hinges from the door frame. I’ve tried hammer/chisel and using a vice grip but there’s not enough space for the former method and no real purchase for the latter.




Those pins are not intended to be removed for security reasons. You could grind the bottom of the pins flat and then hammer the pins out. The small items in the hinges are bearings and it will be difficult to put them back in place when trying to reinstall the pins if you choose to remove them.  My advice would be to shim up the door to take the load off the hinges and unscrew them from the frame or door. Keep the door shimmed up when putting it back in place

Ah, what a pain but thank you for the advice. The goal is to replace damaged weather stripping on the bottom of the door which is a more intensive sounding task than I originally thought.

Why can't you simply remove the hinge screws?  Lining up the hinges to repin will be just as much, if not more a hassle than lining up the door for the hinge screws.

If the pins are giving trouble with removing them, then unscrewing will be faster.
Open the door and add a support under the door at the far end.
Undo three screws of each hinge, then the bottom last screw, with the top screw being last.
If the screws are short you can usually use longer screws for better holding power.
If reusing the screws, turn them in by hand so they match up with the threads already there, before forcing/using power drivers.

Beware that doors are heavy and awkward and will do their best to fall over when you remove the last screw. Your best (or your assistant's best) needs exceed theirs, or foul language may happen at loud volume. An assistant (or two) would be Highly Advisable at that stage.

@Ecnerwal's point holds especially if you didn't hang the doors yourself.  If you put them up, you'll have a feel for them - modern interior doors are manageable solo, but PVC and some other exterior doors can have a lot of heavy steel in there. Also clear the work area of stuff you're not actually using when undoing the last few screws

There are tools that can help with supporting/balancing the door, but an assistant or two is probably easier to deal with if you're not used to it.

In the first and third pictures, when expanded, show that there is a rounded head on the bottom of the hinge pin. A removable pin would not extend beyond the bottom of the leaves, so this is a feature of that model of hinge.
It adds a bit of security, as do the pin/hole pairs in the center of the leaves.
You could remove the head, e.g. with a Dremel, and shorten the pins so that they don't extend beyond the leaves. If you do remove the pins pay attention to the ball bearings and be sure to reinstall them correctly when rehanging the door.

Thank you, this makes sense security-wise.
